# D3 Line Chart Show/Hide Element, Variable Not Defined Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I'm using code similar to this one, and actually plugged in this code to see if I get the same error and I do. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        body { 
            font: 12px Arial;
        }
        path { 
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 2;
            fill: none;
        }
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: grey;
            stroke-width: 1;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
        .legend {
            font-size: 16px;         
            font-weight: bold;         
            text-anchor: start;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 70, left: 50}, 
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
        var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);  

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y0)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);

        var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
        .orient("right").ticks(5);      

        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y0(d.close); });    

        var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y1(d.open); });

        var svg = d3.select("body")

        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        var data = [
            {"date":"9-Apr-12","close":436,"open":9.04},
            {"date":"7-Apr-12","close":221,"open":4.02},
            {"date":"5-Apr-12","close":113,"open":9.02},
            {"date":"4-Apr-12","close":64,"open":32.05},
            {"date":"3-Apr-12","close":29,"open":46.03},
            {"date":"2-Apr-12","close":18,"open":51.03}
        ];

        // Get the data
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            d.open = +d.open;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
        return Math.max(d.close); })]);
        y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
        return Math.max(d.open); })]);

        svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("id", "blueLine")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

        svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", "red")
        .attr("id", "redLine")
        .attr("d", valueline2(data));

        svg.append("g") 
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

        // edit the Y Axis Left
        svg.append("g") 
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("id", "blueAxis")
        .call(yAxisLeft);

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("id", "redAxis")
        .call(yAxisRight);

        // Add the blue line title
        svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)             
        .attr("y", height + margin.top + 10)    
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")         
        .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if current line is visible
            var active   = blueLine.active ? false : true,
              newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            // Hide or show the elements
            d3.select("#blueLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
            d3.select("#blueAxis").style("opacity", newOpacity);
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            blueLine.active = active;
        })
        .text("Blue Line");

        // Add the red line title
        svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 0)             
        .attr("y", height + margin.top + 30)    
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .style("fill", "red")         
        .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if current line is visible
            var active   = redLine.active ? false : true ,
              newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1;
            // Hide or show the elements
            d3.select("#redLine").style("opacity", newOpacity);
            d3.select("#redAxis").style("opacity", newOpacity);
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            redLine.active = active;
        })
        .text("Red Line");
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm getting errors saying that 'blueline' and 'redline' are not defined.

Where do I define those?

I've looked at similar code where the html, css, and js are separated into their own files which is how I've done it also, and other than what I see in the code above I don't find those variables used anyplace else or defined beyond what is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XyIHfgUoutVNhXmezfeS?p=preview) with the code you have there and everything works just fine. Let me explain a little of what is going on though.

Instead of using HTML that is already there, D3 will often generate its own (in fact it has to generate its own to do the visualizations). You see this with statements like the following:

```
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("id", "blueLine")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

D3 just created a path element and appended it to the svg element it created earlier. It gives this particular element an id of `blueLine` which it uses later to apply styles. It did not exist in any HTML prior to this script running. D3 created it.